# WCF Web Api optional parameters in UriTemplate

Tags: wcf, rest, wcf-web-api, uritemplate, webget

How to declare optional parameters in UriTemplate in WCF Web Api ?
For example :

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "?culture={culture}")]
HttpResponseMessage<IEnumerable<Contact>> GetAll();
```

I need culture to be optional parameter. If culture is not passed I want to receive null 
for that param.

PS. I don't want to create solution with multiple GetAll methods with different UriTemplates...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following method declaration culture parameter will be null

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "?culture={culture}")]
HttpResponseMessage<IEnumerable<Contact>> GetAll(string culture);
```